# volley exception file to parse xml configuration fro network security configuration on android version 7

Tags: java, android

After using Samsung galaxy s8 I have been finding this problem every time a make a request with my volley I can't seem to find the solution. Please help.

```
public void checkverification(View view){
    pin=pinView.getText().toString();

    PhoneNumber phoneNumber=new PhoneNumber();
    String urldata=phoneNumber.getUrl();
    String url="http://"+urldata+"/bodapap/selectData.php";

   // String url="http://192.168.43.194/bodapap/selectData.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(VerificationPage.this,"here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("verification");

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject heroObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Hero hero=new Hero(heroObject.getString("verification"));
                    Toast.makeText(VerificationPage.this,hero.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   if(pin.equals(hero.getVerification())){
                       PhoneNumber phoneNumber=new PhoneNumber(phone);


                       Intent intent=new Intent(VerificationPage.this,userRegistration.class);
                       intent.putExtra("phone",phone);
                       startActivity(intent);
                   }else {
                       respondData.setText("Wrong input, pin do not match");
                   }

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            datatext.setText(error.getMessage());

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("phone", phone);
            return parameters;
        }};
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


}}
```

/*
here is the code, this is an exception that only occurs on the Samsung s8 and maybe higher version of android

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the quiz answer is in the manifest i had specified a customer  network security configuration android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config", by removing this statement in the manifest meant using default which worked